# prevent git from tracking symlink to folder

Tags: git

The dir structure of my project looks like this:

```
/home
----- data -> /path/to/another/folder
----- .git/
----- .gitignore
----- folder1
----- folder2
```

The `.gitignore` file contains:

```
/home/data
```

`data` (a link to another folder) currently appears as an untracked file. I thought by adding it to `.gitignore` I could get git to stop following it altogether but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. How do I get `data` to stop showing up in untracked files?

Comment: have you tried git exclude?

Comment: have not, unfamiliar with it. any reason to think that will work and this won't? no idea what the issue is here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The .gitignore file contains:
>
> ```
> /home/data
> ```

Entries in `.gitignore` are relative to the repository, not absolute locations on your disk. It doesn't matter to Git where the repository is stored. From Git's perspective, the structure of your project is this.

```
/
    data -> /path/to/another/folder
    .gitignore
    folder1
    folder2
```

So you want to tell Git to ignore `/data`.

The leading slash says to only ignore `data` at the top of the repository. `folder1/data` will not be ignored.

The lack of a trailing slash is important. If there was a trailing slash `git` would look for a directory, not a symlink to a directory.

Comment: interesting: i tried `./data` earlier and that didn't work, could you explain why that would be the case?

Comment: @Alex: the path name Git sees does not have a leading `./`. In some places Git will resolve it away, but apparently not in your `.gitignore` file. `/data` should work but `./data` is not expected to work.

Comment: @Alex Because "*Git treats the pattern as a shell glob*" and uses "*[fnmatch(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch) and the FNM_PATHNAME flag*". I think torek is right that Git is matching the pattern `./data` against the simple filename `data`. See [dir.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/dir.c) and [wildmatch.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/wildmatch.c) for all the details.